# openssl_pkcs7_encrypt S/MIME

Tags: php

Разбираюсь с самописной админкой и решил заморочится с настройкой штатного сендмейла для отсылки писем( подтверждение регистрации, восстановление пароля итд. НЕ спам).
DKIM spf DMARC всё настроено. 
Решил настроить дополнительно шифрование S/MIME, нашёл функцию php [openssl_pkcs7_encrypt](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.openssl-pkcs7-encrypt.php) . 
Может ли кто то подсказать подробнее как с ней работать? 
infile - файл с самим письмом.
outfile - файл куда запишем зашифрованое письмо.
headers - заголовки письма.

recipcerts - Массив, либо единичный сертификат X.509. 
И вот с сертификатом есть вопрос. Достаточно сгенерировать самому самоподписаный? Или нужно получить у довереного центра?

UPD 12.11.2018
Провел тесты - 
1) сгенерировал свой сертификат - письмо ушло но почтовые клиенты не имеющие этого сертификата не могут расшифровать письмо (что логично).
2) получил у Комодо [Free Secure Email Certificate](https://www.comodo.com/home/email-security/free-email-certificate.php) . Функция отрабатывает без ошибок. Но письмо не доходит до адресата. Сертификат регистрировал на почту с которой происходит отправка.

UPD 14.11.2018
Использовать можно свой сертификат. Для дешифровки письма нужно чтобы открытый ключ был доступен адресату (добавлен в почтовый клиент). Получатели письма у которых отсутствует публичный ключ, не смогут прочитать письмо.

Comment: т.е. вопрос исчерпан?

Comment: да. Віяснил сам всё что хотел узнать. Вопрос не удаляю может кому пригодиться, ибо информациив сети мало.